# Mongodb update a collection based on another collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two collections
The structure of collection one is

```
{'click_id':"123345",
...
}
```

The structure of collection two is

```
{'click_id':"123345",
...

}
```

What is the optimal way to do the following in collection 1

```
{'click_id':"123345",
'collection2':true,
...
    }
```

considering the fact there are around 1 billion records in collection 1 and around 30 million records in collection 2.

Comment: what about uniqueness of click_id in both collection?

Comment: click_id is unique in both the collections

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't do stuff like JOIN from SQL DBs on MongoDB.

If your job is batch and you can think of the second collection as of a state snapshot, you could just load all the 30 million IDs into memory (should be under 1 GB, but it depends on the length of the IDs) as dictionary/map.

Then go through all the 1 billion records from the 1st collection and save the results in Bulk insert/update (IDK what you want).